# How to receive mail from gmail by using gmail gem n rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, gmail, rubygems

I want to receive the mail from gmail gem into my rails app, I am able to receive the mail by using following code in my controller

home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @gmail = Gmail.connect("myemail.com","mypassword")
    @rec = @gmail.inbox.mails()     
  end
end
```

---

app/view/index.html

```
<h1>Mails</h1>

<table border="3" cellpadding="10">
<%= @rec.each do |mail| %>
    <tr><td><%= mail.message.body.raw_source.create %></td></tr>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Here I do get the mail but alog with additional headers and information. I just want to get the email subject and body.

Is there any solution to this using "gmail gem" or will I need to use something else ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the GMail Gem but the [Mail Gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail) itself will do the parsing of this information. You can use the [Mail Gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail) to parse the contents of the email and pull out the subject and html information.

You may also want to take a look at my blog post on [receiving email in rails using a test driven approach](http://steve.dynedge.co.uk/2010/11/29/receiving-test-driven-incoming-email-for-rails-3/), it might not apply directly but it shows some thoughts on how you can separate out some of the logic away from using the controller directly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<%= mail.message.body.raw_source.create %>` you must do

```
<%= mail.subject %>
<%= mail.body %>
```